# Bilinear interpolation example

Tags: interpolation

I just do not understand what we are supposed to do when we want to scale a matrix with using the method of bilinear interpolation. Let's say we hjave a 3x3 matrix as written below.
\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\1&2&2\\1&2&3&\end{bmatrix}

Can you please one of you guys show me step by step how to scale this matrix by the factor of 2 both vertically and horizontally?

Comment: What do you mean? You need to get a 6x6 matrix?

Comment: @YuriyS yes I do but I do not understand how to apply bilinear interpolation.

Comment: Have you read about it? There's a Wikipedia page and many other sources